# Proof of Knuth's Theorem

Tags: monte-carlo

Hey there I'm looking for the proof of Knuth's Theorem such that it satisfies its following formulation:

The linear congruential generator $h(x) = (ax + c) \mod k$ has cycle length $k$, if and only if

**(1)** $c$ are $k$ relatively prime

**(2)** every prime factor of $k$ divides $a − 1$

**(3)** if $4$ divides $k$, then $4$ divides $a − 1$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you looked at, say, Knuth? (specifically vol. 2 of _The Art of Computer Programming_, chapter 3, on random number generation...)